# Adding session in while (mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
   mysql_select_db('chatbox',$con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users");
   mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `online` = 0 WHERE `username` = ".$username."");
}
```

Can you make the username is session (that is logged in) to be equal to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `online` = 0 WHERE `username` = "to_put_it_here");
```

Comment: Sure you can, it's as easy as sticking it in there, but only in principle, in real life you have to make sure the value is safe, and on that note you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions either.

Comment: it's for school project it doesn't need to be safe, just functional. And like this it says that username is undefined

Comment: How and where are you setting the session? Try echoing $_SESSION['usename'] to see it's value before querying

Comment: Tried and won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and cute trick

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];    
if(isset($username))
{
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
   mysql_select_db('chatbox',$con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users");
   mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `online` = 0 WHERE `username` = '$username' ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would be using PDO. Although I think this would help you

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `online` = 0 WHERE `username` = $_SESSION['username']);
```